# Java streams: one liner to perform multiple numeric operations on Int stream

Tags: java, lambda, stream, java-8, java-stream

I have been reading about Java 8, but have not tried it out yet. So, I'm attempting to do simple math operations using it.

I'm trying to find the average, sum, max, and minimum of a list using new techniques from Java 8. I want to print out all the numbers in the collection first, and then print out average, sum, min, and max.

Here is what I have:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5,6,2,12,7,9,15,18,-1,-8);
OptionalDouble average = list.stream().mapToInt(num -> num).average();
int sum = list.stream().mapToInt(num -> num).sum();
//sort the numbers, so that min and max are found in array
int[] arr = list.stream().mapToInt(a -> {System.out.println(a); return a;}).sorted().toArray();
System.out.println("Average: " + average.getAsDouble());
System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
System.out.println("The minimum is: " + arr[0] + ", and maximum: " + arr[arr.length-1]);
```

Is there a way to do this with one stream initiation instead of making 3 different streams? Is there a way to perform multiple, parallel, operations on one single stream source?

Also, what if I was to get the numbers I'm performing operations on from the terminal/console, instead of it already being in a collection. If I recall correctly, `Java 8 In Action` describes one of the differences between `Collections` and `Streams` as `Collections` already having all their elements stored, while `Streams` continuously getting their data from the source, element by element. So, this is similar to a user providing numbers via the console, one by one. So, my second question is, is it possible to make the data source for a stream the `System.in` instead of having to make a `List` first from the user input, and then converting that `List` to a stream?

Comment: `mapToInt(a -> {System.out.println(a); return a;})` -- this is not recommended; prefer `peek(System.out::println)`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Should I use `peek()` also when I need to perform something using the elements, but don't need it to be passed along the stream? Example if I wanted to make a string of the numbers in an array: `StringJoiner nums = new StringJoiner(",", "The numbers provided were: ", ".\n")` and then the stream: `list.stream().peek(a -> nums.add(a.toString())).mapToDouble(a -> a).summaryStatistics();` OR is there a better way to do side operations using the stream elements?

Comment: Please don't.  Use a proper collector for things like that.

Comment: [this](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/308979/168903) is why I shouldn't have used `peek()`, as @LouisWasserman said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have the `IntStream`, call [`summaryStatistics()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics--) to get back an `IntSummaryStatistics` object that holds the count, sum, min, max, and average.

Generally, you can call [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.ObjIntConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) on the `IntStream` to perform your own customized calculations on the stream values.  Pass in a `Supplier` that supplies the initial state of the calculations (e.g. sum is `0`).  Pass in a `ObjIntConsumer` that processes the current value into the state of the calculations (e.g. a value is added to the sum).  Pass in a `BiConsumer` that merges the results of two separate calculations (used in parallel calculations) (e.g. two sums are added together and stored in the first sum).

I know of no built-in way of converting an input stream to a `java.util.streams.Stream`.  The most straightforward way is to do as you already suggest - read from the input, store the values in a `List`, then process it with a `Stream`.  This certainly works, but it is like a "full barrier" - the whole contents must be in memory at once before further processing can take place.

If I were to create something that would convert input from an `InputStream` to a `java.util.streams.Stream`, I would have some kind of `Reader` or `Scanner` inside of a custom implementation of `Spliterator.ofInt`, which would read and parse the `int` values on demand.  Then you could pass an instance of this custom `Spliterator.ofInt` to [`StreamSupport.intStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html#intStream-java.util.Spliterator.OfInt-boolean-) to create an `IntStream`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion in the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: @rgettman Also, `summaryStatistics()` will solve this particular problem, but I'm still wondering if there is a way to perform multiple parallel operations on a stream, whether it is changing elements in the stream or not

Comment: @Abdul I already added the second paragraph about calling `collect` with your own implementations of `Supplier`, `ObjIntConsumer`, and `BiConsumer` that perform your own custom calculations.  This is valid whether the stream is parallel or not.

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment should have been `mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)` I am not sure what I was thinking...

Comment: I don't know, man. Stream is supposed to simplify our code. But a lot of examples I saw on SO seem to be just asking for trouble by using Stream. I guess, if it's not obvious how to solve a problem with Stream, it probably should not be solved with Stream :)

Comment: @erickson Could you readd your previous comment please? I did not save it

Comment: @Abdul It should have been something like this: `new BufferedReader(System.console().reader()).lines().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)...` If users enter numbers, one per line, this will give you an `IntStream`

Comment: @erickson You should add that as another answer, since it's an answer to part of the original question. (I was considering doing that until I saw your comment.)